# Arduino, creating multiple same objects inside another class?

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor, arduino

I'm new to this and really need your help. I'm looking a way to make multiple objects of class named LED inside another class named Multiple_led.

Firstly I created LED class:

```
class LED{
byte pin;

  public:
    LED(byte attachTo): pin(attachTo){
      pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
      digitalWrite(pin,LOW);
      }

    void lightOn(){
      digitalWrite(pin,HIGH);
      }
    void lightOff(){
      digitalWrite(pin,LOW);
      }
 };
```

Then I created another class which inherits LED class:

```
class Multiple_led: public LED {

 LED led1;
 LED led2;
 LED led3; 
  public:

  Multiple_led(byte a, byte b, byte c): LED (led1(a)), LED (led2(b)), LED (led3(c)){ };

  };
```

The problem is that I don't know how to make constructor so that I can create multiple LED objects with just one instance of Multiple_led class.
For example later in code I want to write Multiple_led Leds(3,4,5,6) and simultaneously create 4 LED objects which I can work with inside Multiple_led class.

What's the best way to approach this kind of issue?

Comment: **Don't**. Instead, design a class with a method `bool add(LED* led);` or `bool add(int pin)` that stores in an internal *static fixed-size vector of reasonable size* either the reference to `LED*` or the `int` pin, depending on what you want to do with these things later on. *Arduino* has very limited computing and memory resources, there is no reason to waste them on unnecessary features which only add extra complexity for tiny projects.

Comment: You can do it with http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list